# Laravel 5.1 firstOrNew

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to be able to insert a new record into the database if it doesn't already exist.  If it does exist I want to update the existing record with the new info.

Basically, the field that I want to check to see if it exists is called 'token'.

So, I have tried something like this:

```
$this->timesheet->firstOrNew(['token' => '12345'])->save();
```

This successfully creates the new row.

How do I pass in the other fields that I want to insert/update?  For example `first_name`, `last_name`?

Can I do something like:

```
$this->timesheet->firstOrNew(['token' => '12345'])->update(['first_name' => 'Bob', 'last_name' => 'Smith'])->save();
```

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens? Are you getting some kind of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `firstOrNew`, then follow it up with a call to `fill` and `save`:

```php
$this->timesheet->firstOrNew(['token' => '12345'])
     ->fill(['first_name' => 'Bob', 'last_name' => 'Smith'])
     ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the object. Fill it with the other information that you want to save.

```
$timesheet = $this->timesheet->firstOrNew(['token' => '12345']);
$timesheet->fill(['first_name' => 'Bob', 'last_name' => 'Smith']);
$timesheet->save();
```